# MVC4 Model Binding - Null Values

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I know there are a bunch of questions on this already - I'm having a hard time sorting out which ones are related to problems with versions, and which ones are related to jQuery (which I'm not using), etc. I have the MVC4 RC (4.0.20505.0), Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1.

I have a complex type in my model:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri]Person person)
    {
        TableStorageHelper personHelper = new TableStorageHelper();
        personHelper.Save(personHelper.GetTableNameForType("Person"), person);

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Person>(HttpStatusCode.Created, person);
        return response;
    }
```

I am passing in this JSON string - using Fiddler mostly, but also trying from code in another controller (trying to do all testing locally just to verify that I can get values in the object received by the controller):

The JSON:

```
{"FirstName":"Andy","LastName":"Schultz","PartitionKey":"USW","RowKey":"per-928c8f74-2efd-4fc2-a71c-fb3ea8acc6d7","NickName":null,"FullName":"Andy Schultz","Description":null,"ImageLocation":null,"Region":"USW","CommentsAboutMe":{"Comments":[]},"CommentsByMe":{"Comments":[]}}
```

All of the properties here do exist in the class.

The code from the other controller:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.2:8080/api/persons/") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/json";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            Person person = new Person("Andy", "Schultz", "USW");
            Formatting formatting = new Formatting();
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, formatting, settings);

            writer.Write(json);
        }
```

Every time, I get an empty Person object in my controller (I'm debugging on the very first line there). Every value is NULL.

You may have noticed the [FromUri] attribute on  my controller - I had to do that to get around an error telling me there was no ModelBinder for an undefined type, but I'm not sure that it's correct - I'm not passing any info in the Uri, it's in the body, as you can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mike Stall: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

The [FromUri] attribute did indeed tell my controller to read the uri and not the request body looking for the parameter for my controller method. It wasn't there, so everything was null.

The error that adding that attribute fixed, which said there was no formatter defined for a type of content Undefined, was caused by my improperly declaring the content-type of the request. The correct way was "Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8